# water jug problem GCD solution explanation

Tags: algorithm

I could not solve below problem. Can you help me with some solution?

```
You are given two jugs with capacities jug1Capacity and jug2Capacity liters. There is an infinite amount of water supply available. Determine whether it is possible to measure exactly targetCapacity liters using these two jugs.

If targetCapacity liters of water are measurable, you must have targetCapacity liters of water contained within one or both buckets by the end.

Operations allowed:

Fill any of the jugs with water.
Empty any of the jugs.
Pour water from one jug into another till the other jug is completely full, or the first jug itself is empty.
Example - 
Input: jug1Capacity = 3, jug2Capacity = 5, targetCapacity = 4
Output: true
Input: jug1Capacity = 2, jug2Capacity = 6, targetCapacity = 5
Output: false
Input: jug1Capacity = 1, jug2Capacity = 2, targetCapacity = 3
Output: true
```

I found below solution on net but could not understood the logic behind this solution.

```
class Solution {
private:
    int gcd (int a, int b) {
        return b ? gcd (b, a % b) : a;
    }
public:
    bool canMeasureWater(int jug1Capacity, int jug2Capacity, int targetCapacity) {
        return jug1Capacity+jug2Capacity>=targetCapacity ? !(targetCapacity%gcd(jug1Capacity,jug2Capacity)) : false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is a partially broken application of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which says that if *a* and *b* be are integers with greatest common divisor *d*, then the set of integers of the form *ax* + *by* (*x*, *y* also integers) is exactly the set of integer multiples of *d*.  The linked Wikipedia article provides a proof.

To see that that applies to the problem, simply observe that the only operations you can perform that allow you to keep an accurate measure of the volume boil down to adding or removing water one full jug at a time.  The volumes you can measure that way are exactly the sums of integer multiples of `jug1Capacity` and `jug2Capacity`, and that is the form addressed by Bézout.

Observe, next, that the aptly named `gcd()` method applies [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute the greatest common divisor of its arguments.

Then observe that `targetCapacity % gcd(jug1Capacity,jug2Capacity)` computes the remainder of dividing `targetCapacity` by the GCD of `jug1Capacity` and `jug2Capacity`. This evaluates to 0 if and only if `targetCapacity` is a multiple of the GCD.

The code then assumes that in boolean context, 0 evaluates to false and non-zero evaluates to true (as in C++), so the sense of that result is reversed via the logical negation operator (`!`) to yield the final answer.

The code presented in the program is flawed, however, in that it is incorrect to reject inputs on the basis of `jug1Capacity + jug2Capacity` being less than `targetCapacity`.  If either input is 1, for example, then *every* target can be measured.  Possibly the wanted condition is instead `jug1Capacity != 0 || jug2Capacity != 0`, if you don't want to assume that as a precondition.  In C or C++, that can be abbreviated to `jug1Capacity || jug2Capacity`.

Comment: Let say Jug1 capacity is 3 and Jug2 capacity is 5 and we want to measure 2 liters. So we can first fill second jug with 5 liters an then transfer 3 liters to first jug and empty first jug. Now second jug has only 2 liters. But can we get 2 from equation ax + by?

Comment: @sachin, 2 = 3 * (-1) + 5 * 1

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is good. But you *can* fill a jug with a different amount than x or y. For example, lets say you have a 3 capacity and a 7 capacity jug. You can fill the 7 with the 3 twice, then fill it with only 1. It's not that you can only fill by x or y, it's that you can only fill with a *linear combination* of x or y in each step. In this case, 1 = 7(1)+3(-2)

Also, the algorithm is not wrong to include as a condition that x + y must add up to the target. Yes, any linear combination can be measured, but only targets less than or equal to x + y can be contained by one or both buckets